# How to list all 2nd level subfolders and delete un-required ones?

Tags: windows-xp

I provide support to a lot of clients. I have created a folder for each client, and under each client folder, I create a folder for the date on which the issue was reported.

Now due to growing data, I want to delete all issues for all clients which are before a cut off date.

The problem is while creating the date folder, I have not always followed a specific convention, some are creating using dd-MM-yyyy, some are using dd.MM.yyyy, etc.

Is there a quick way I can list all such date subfolders, and then choose which ones I do not want, and delete them?

Comment: an old logic would be you can create a customized **.bat** file which will do this stuff for you :)

Comment: I have worked with batch files long ago. How can I select folders in batch file, since they do not follow a standard naming convention. If I can see the folder search results in explorer for only 2nd level folders, then I can quickly decide which ones I want to delete. Alternately, we can do it based on folder creation date time. I feel a GUI based solution will be better, but can you give me some more clues about batch file, like which set of commands will be helpful in this case

Comment: I have gone through forfiles command, but it is based on last modified date time, not created date time.

Comment: for the GUI base solution, you can develop a customized application in Visual Basic 6.0, its easy one.

Comment: I am looking for some utility which is ready. I do not want to get into programming for this.

Comment: Let me reformulate your problem: You want to delete folders containing 2009, 2010, maybe 2011 in the folder name. Use Windows Explorer to do this by searching for *2009*. You will get a list with all this folders, delete them all. Then search for *2010*, delete them all. This is easy. And the search string for the current year until the cut-off date is a little bit more work but just search for *2012*01, *2012*02, ... I doubt there is an easier solution. Let me know if you found one.

Comment: Thats great. I did not think of this at all. However, for current year, its a bit more work as you also said. Do you know of any regular expression based search tool, so that I can get all folders in a single search operation and then delete them?

Comment: If u know of any regular expression based tool, pls let me know; otherwise post your above comment as an answer so that I can accept it. 1 more thing. Suppose I want to retain the folders, but only empty their contents. Is there any way? I may require this to keep a statistics of how many issues on which I have given support.

Comment: [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) supports RegEx (not to be taken literally, of course :)

Comment: Hi Karan and gentlesea, can you please post your comments as answers, so that I can accept them?

Answer (score 0):

in [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) with Cntl+B you see the whole files under those folder and delete that you want

if your files or folders have similar attribute , i could help you more.

you can use another tools like  [Servant Salamander](http://download.cnet.com/Servant-Salamander-Full/3000-2248_4-173119.html)